# Lenovo Legion Y520 boot media failed or missing even after replacement

Tags: boot, ssd, lenovo-laptop, m.2

Over the past few weeks I had some trouble with my [Lenovo Legion Y520](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/in/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/legion-series/legion-y520-15ikba?linkTrack=Homepage%3ABody_Search%20Products&searchType=3&keyWordSearch=Legion%20Y520-15IKBA%20Laptop%20(Lenovo)). Multiple BSOD with exceptions that lead to my storage and my laptop not booting up with the message 'boot failed or missing' for a few minutes.

After that my M.2 drive just boots up again and the cycle starts again. I tried the 'chkdsk' command multiple times without results. Even when I bought a replacement M.2 drive, after an hour it stopped working and gave the same message again. After shutting down and starting up again it started my drive with no problems. Could this be a problem in the M.2 slot?

Comment: @K7AAY i forgot to mention that both the old and the new ssd are m.2 drives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not much I can do at the moment. It most likely is some problem to the connection in the M.2 Slot.